# Code dependent on Console

Tags: java, netbeans

I need some help with this code I managed to find on the Internet,here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

class login {
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        Scanner luci = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String idInput;
        System.out.println("Username: "); 
        idInput = luci.nextLine(); 
        String passwordInput; 
        System.out.print("Password: "); 
        passwordInput = luci.nextLine(); 

        if(passwordInput.equals("PASSWORD_GOES_HERE") &&  (idInput.equals("USERNAME_GOES_HERE"))){ 
            System.out.println("Authentification complete!"); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong ID or Password!"); 
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code in Netbeans it works perfectly, but there is one problem, it is dependent on the console, you need to give it the login information in the console.Is there any way I can make this code work outside of Netbeans?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do after login is successful? Are you trying to run it from command line or something?

Comment: `Is there any way I can make this code work outside of Netbeans?` This code works on Eclipse too. After all, you're reading input from `System.in` which isn't specific to Netbeans.

Comment: this is a basic program which uses console as output, there are several choices you can pick, 1. redirect the output into txt (just like the comment above), 2. you can use command prompt as compiler, 3. you can attach jtextfield into your program, 4. you can use joptionpane.

Comment: By saying,`Is there any way I can make this code work outside of Netbeans`, I'am saying is it possible to make it work on the desktop of a normal computer.

Comment: @peeskillet I'am going to then make it run my program if the login is accepted.

Comment: What kind of program is it? A console program? A gui program?

Comment: @A-SM How would I go about redirecting it into txt?
Sorry, I'm a noob...

Comment: @peeskillet I would like to turn it into a GUI program, but I don't know how...

Comment: You should really go over some basic [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html)

Comment: @peeskillet Okay, I will look at the link you have given me, thanks.

Comment: And take a look at the [Swing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for Gui programs

Comment: a simple example for gui program: change `System.out.println("Authentification complete!");` into `JoptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Authentication complete");` and `System.out.println("Wrong ID or Password!");` into `JoptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Authentication failed");`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing it to the console, you can store the result in a String variable and write it to a file as shown below:

```
    String s;

    if (passwordInput.equals("PASSWORD_GOES_HERE")
            && (idInput.equals("USERNAME_GOES_HERE"))) {

        s="Authentification complete!";

    } else {
        s="Wrong ID or Password!";

    }

    try {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("Select file name");
        int option = chooser.showSaveDialog(foo);
        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath())).print(s);               
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```